# Programmatically reset the selected elements of an entity browser widget

Tags: entities, 9

What I am trying to do, when the value of a field changes, reset and show the original selection widget.

For example:

1.- The first time the browser widget is displayed.

[image: 1 step]

2.- After having added an element to the browser, it would look like this.

[image: 2 second step]

3.- If I check the checkbox to reset, it should go back to the original state

[image: 3 reset step]

What would be the path to take to achieve this behavior?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, could you use Paragraphs and create entities that can be edited or deleted with that?

Comment: I am validating certain behaviors, when certain fields change their value I require to reset the elements that may be selected in the browser, to force the user to select it again.